# How to convert crlf in git repository?

Tags: git

From converting CVS/SVN repositories to git I ended up with this situation (new -> old) in git:

1. commit with CRLF in repo
2. commit with CRLF in repo
3. commit with CRLF in repo
4. commit with LF in repo
5. commit with LF in repo

This gives me incorrect diffs between `3.` and `4.`  So I want this to be:

1. commit with LF in repo
2. commit with LF in repo
3. commit with LF in repo
4. commit with LF in repo
5. commit with LF in repo

How can I get this done in git?  `git rebase` would be ideal as I also need to squash a few commits.  I don't care about line endings on my local disk for this.  Might setting `git config core.autocrlf` help?  I usually run with `core.autocrlf=false`.  This is on Windows and will be Windows only.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/293941/rewrite-git-history-to-replace-all-crlf-to-lf

Comment: Thanks, that's an option. But it won't be git that's doing the conversion.  So how to be sure not to convert images and the like?